# Disable Fody Costura

Tags: fody, fody-costura

Is there a way to disable Fody Costura? I need to perform some troubleshooting and I want to know that Fody Costura is not part of the problem. I would prefer to disable it instead of removing the nuget which would be one solution.

Removing `<Costura/>` from the Fody configuration gives the following error since I do not use any other weavers:

`Fody: No configured weavers. It is possible you have not installed a weaver or have installed a fody weaver nuget into a project type that does not support install.ps1. You may need to add that weaver to FodyWeavers.xml manually. eg. <Weavers><WeaverName/></Weavers>. see https://github.com/Fody/Fody/wiki/SampleUsage`

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can comment out or remove the `<Costura />` line from `FodyWeavers.xml`

Comment: It doesn't work since it is the only weaver I am using.

Comment: This works for me - I found out by accident when reinstalling Costura and the `FodyWeavers.xml` file had been emptied. Checking the IL Manifest confirmed that the assemblies were not embedded and the build output showed that Costura didn't find any weavers.

Comment: It works for me too. But I had to Rebuild the project for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

open the .csproj file, search for "fody", then remove all the tags that include it. such as

```
 <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\dotnet\Fody.targets')" />
```

those are after this tag

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
```

Comment: There are more lines to delete if you used `Install-CleanReferencesTarget` command line in the package manager console: Also delete everything from the line `<UsingTask TaskName="CosturaCleanup" .... ` to `</UsingTask>`

Comment: It's true, the uninstall script seems to foget these lines.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no way to turn off Costura but you can exclude all of your references manually:

```
<Costura>
    <ExcludeAssemblies>
        Foo
        Bar
    </ExcludeAssemblies>
</Costura>
```

Notice it doesn't include `.dll`/`.exe` extension (it's `Foo` instead of `Foo.dll`)

Also, if you are embedding native / unmanaged dll, make sure you switched Build Action of those libraries to None

For more information:
https://github.com/Fody/Costura#excludeassemblies

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. It really works if you only have one weaver installed I (just tested it), it is clean, upwards compatible, doens't mess with poject files and will give you the error message "Error 8 Fody: A re-build is required to apply the changes from 'C:\Foo\Bar\FodyWeavers.xml'. FooBar". But guess what you have to do :-)

Comment: And you can keep the current version of Costura installed for the project. That gave one headache one time, when I installed a newer version which I din't notice first when "reactivating" it (made huge problems with Newtonsoft.Json).

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/143#issuecomment-378612705

```
<DisableFody Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">true</DisableFody>
```

Comment: This solution disables everything. I wish to disable only Costura.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread, but I found success also with including an empty IncludeAssemlies section in FodyWeavers.xml.  Costura then includes none.

```
 <IncludeAssemblies>
  </IncludeAssemblies>
```